# TestCafe - How to add multiple filters in the testcaferc.js configuration file

Tags: node.js, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am trying to filter out certain test names **and** set the testMeta of scope=sanity. This is what I currently have set up (based on [TestCafe - How to have multiple regex for testGrep in testcaferc file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70186825/testcafe-how-to-have-multiple-regex-for-testgrep-in-testcaferc-file/70212396)) which I would expect to work but it doesn't appear to.

```
filter: ((testName, testMeta) => 
    // Located in editor_page_tests.js
    !testName.includes('user_is_able_to_add_a_section_column_row_and_element_to_editor') &&
    !testName.includes('pop_up_element_displays_during_page_preview') &&
    !testName.includes('clicking_button_shows_hides_elements') &&
    !testName.includes('user_is_able_to_save_when_adding_a_video') &&
    !testName.includes('user_is_able_to_save_when_leaving_video_embed_blank') &&

    // Located in blog_page_tests.js
    !testName.includes('user_can_create_a_blog') &&

    // Located in courses_page_tests.js
    !testName.includes('user_can_preview_existing_course') &&

    // Located in url_redirects_page_tests.js
    !testName.includes('user_is_able_to_edit_url_redirect') &&
    
    // Located in funnels_page_tests.js
    !testName.includes('user_can_navigate_through_funnel') &&

    testMeta.scope === 'sanity'
    )
```

I am able to use `testGrep` and Regex to make it do the thing but it's definitely not the most organized way of doing things.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I prepared an example that demonstrates the filtering capabilities. Note that the parameters in the 'filter' function of the configuration file are the same as in the [Runner.filter](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402657/reference/testcafe-api/runner/filter#header) method.

1. **test.js**

```js
    import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
    
    const nameInput = Selector('#developer-name');
    
    fixture`My fixture`
        .page`https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example/`;
    
    test.meta({ metaKey: 'meta1'})('test name', async t => {
        await t.typeText(nameInput, 'a')
    });
    
    test.meta({metaKey: 'meta value'})('test name', async t => {
        await t.typeText(nameInput, 'b')
    });
```

2. **.testcaferc.js**

```js
    module.exports = {
        src: './test.js',
        filter: ((testName, fixtureName, fixturePath, testMeta, fixtureMeta)  
        => testName === 'test name' && testMeta.metaKey === 'meta value')    }
```